# Prove that (p → q) → ((r ∨ p) → (r ∨ q)) is a tautology without using truth table

Tags: math, computer-science, discrete-mathematics, discrete

I can't find a proper formula for this considering it's almost exclusively made up of implications. Can somebody help me?

just I want to know how to simplify it.

I tried this but still no correct answer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0QQt.jpg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should be on https://math.stackexchange.com/.   To know what is on-topic on Stackoverflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If r is false, then ((r ∨ p) → (r ∨ q)) is just (p → q).

If r is true, then ((r ∨ p) → (r ∨ q)) is just (true → true).